# 14.04 how can i dualboot and install windows 10 as ubuntu user?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10, amd-graphics, gpu

I have been a ubuntu user for over a year now. not a fan of the convoluted vocabulary of the terminal, but i loved the visual presentation this OS gives, it is also great for work, experiment, program and to play emulators. However the (steam) gaming aspects are... disappointing. and quite bad really. not only my gpu is quite incompatible with the os (amd r9 radeon 380) and i can't even play shadow of mordor! I need an os exclusive for gaming (while also having my ubuntu) and that's why i downloaded a windows 10 iso file. well now i don't know what to do. I know there are some similar questions that others made here. but there were some terms that i couldn't understand (like what even is gparted? and how does it work?) and google showed very old post so i want to ask to you guys how to dual boot after installing ubuntu? it needs to be as foolproof as possible please, especially when it gets to the part of installing windows and afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

gparted is a partition manager for the disk drives. Once you have partitions, you can put different operating systems on different partitions. Then you use some tool to control the boot process, so you can select which one boots at any given time.

If you have high-end hardware, install VirtualBox and run Windows inside a VirtualBox. That is not dual-boot. Instead you get both at once, and you can fully backup your Win10 system.

Here is a site that explains the steps for Ubuntu and Windows with screenshots: 
[lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony)

For a commercial solution, Terabyte Inc offers a well-documented product line to assist with multi-boot systems. Look at [BootIT Bare Metal](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-bare-metal.htm).

Comment: can i play steam games properly on virtualbox? if yes, how much RAM and storage should it have? i have 8 gigas of RAM and i have 561 gigas  free of use. Also how my virtual windows will handle the drivers and the gpu itself?